# How to localize UI files in PySide

Tags: localization, translation, pyside

I created an application which loads its UI dynamically from UI files (added to resources of application. I have't translate in with `poyside-uic`, loading as is. now I want lo localize application, but do not understand how.

I tried to generate TS file using `pyside-lupdate widge1.ui widget2.ui ... -ts my.ts` and got document with multiple `context` nodes and linguist does not shows all records (only about 7 records and I do not understand which exact).

So, my question: how to translate dynamically loaded UI files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Quite simple, but not always obvious.

1. Execute `pyside-lupdate file1.ui file2.ui .... fileN.ui -ts translations\ru_RU.ts`. Got a TS file after that with multiple contexts (it is ok, I was wrong)
2. Open TS with linguist. Ensure that option 'Context' checked in menu "View->View"
3. ...
4. PROFIT!!!